# Stored procedure with parameter validation for job name

Tags: sql

I would like to create a stored procedure in SQL that executes only jobs that are specified in the parameter validation of the procedure itself. For example I would like my dev team to only be able to pass the job names that I specify that way they will be able to run the jobs they need only. From their perspective it will look something like this.

```
Exec sp_run_only_jobs myjob
```

or

```
Exec sp_run_only_jobs myotherjob
```

if they try to run a job other than the two above it should fail with an error message.

I

Comment: Can you give more detail? What have you tried?  What's not working?

Comment: I presume you know how to run a job from command line? `exec msdb.dbo.sp_start_job @job_name = 'myjob'` The rest is up to you. Any issue with this?

Comment: Procedural code is **highly vendor-specific** - so please add a tag to specify whether you're using `mysql`, `postgresql`, `sql-server`, `oracle` or `db2` - or something else entirely.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can create a stored procedure to check if the specified job name falls under a specific list of jobs, then execute the job. Otherwise, throw error message.

```
CREATE PROCEDURE dbo.usp_run_only_jobs @JobName NVARCHAR(4000)
AS
BEGIN
    IF @JobName EXISTS IN ('AllowedJob1', 'AllowedJob2')
    BEGIN 
        EXEC msdb.dbo.sp_start_job @JobName ;  
    END
    ELSE
    BEGIN
        THROW 51000, 'The specified job is not allowed to be started', 1;
    END
END
```

Comment: Thanks Venkat, seems like this code might work. I will give it a try tomorrow and let you know.

Comment: @Darkswap, glad, that it worked. Please mark it as answer, so that it is helpful for others.